# long division is not properly displayed in Mathjax

Tags: mathjax

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mlongdiv charalign="center" charspacing="0px" stackalign="left">
        <mn>8</mn>
        <mrow>
            <none></none>
            <mn>3</mn>
        </mrow>
        <msgroup>
            <mn>251</mn>
            <msrow>
                <menclose notation="bottom">
                    <mn>2</mn>
                </menclose>
                <menclose notation="bottom">
                    <mn>4</mn>
                </menclose>
            </msrow>
            <msrow>
                <none></none>
                <mn>1</mn>
            </msrow>
        </msgroup>
    </mlongdiv>
</math>
```

This is how it's currently displayed(https://jsbin.com/gobojih/edit?html,output)
[image: mathjax-long-division-bug]

This is how it's displayed in wiris Mathtype demo page(https://demo.wiris.com/mathtype/en/developers.php)
[image: mathtype-wiris-bug]

Answer (score 0):

The MML3 extension is experimental, and may not real all possible elementary math expressions, or handle all possible attribute values.  Also, the output is not always optimal.

In your case, the outermost `<msgroup>` is causing problems, as the extension doesn't seem to read it properly.  If you move the `<mn>251</mn>` outside the `msgroup`, that will allow the output to render better.

The MML3 extension doesn't handle the `<none>` element, but changing the `nrow` that contains it to be `<mn>3&#xA0;</mn>` allows that to render in the way you indicate.  So

```xml
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mlongdiv charalign="center" charspacing="0px" stackalign="left">
        <mn>8</mn>
        <mn>3&#xA0;</mn>
        <mn>251</mn>
        <msgroup position="1">
            <msrow>
                <menclose notation="bottom">
                    <mn>2</mn>
                </menclose>
                <menclose notation="bottom">
                    <mn>4</mn>
                </menclose>
            </msrow>
            <mn>1</mn>
        </msgroup>
    </mlongdiv>
</math>
```

renders as

[image]

which may be sufficient for your needs.  This does mean you will need to edit the MathType output, I'm sorry to say.